# Getting dynamic value in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I am new to iOS Native, I have an experience of Flutter and in flutter we have a keyword dynamic and we can return dynamic value from function. I want this too in Swift but when i am trying to achieve this i am getting this error

`Type of expression is ambiguous without a type annotation`

Here's my dummy code:

```
func returnValue(_ flag: Bool) -> Any {
    if flag {
        return "A string"
    } else {
        return 42 // An integer
    }
}

let result = returnValue(true)
```

Can you tell me how can i do this in Swift

Answer (score 1):

The code seems correct, if the function is returning `Any` we just need to do check type in runtime.

```
if let stringResult = result as? String {
    print("String: \(stringResult)")
} else if let intResult = result as? Int {
    print("Int: \(intResult)")
} else {
    print("I do not know what is the type")
}
```